# MVC 4 Deployment to IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I know there are Q & A's that seem to discuss this at length, but I'm thinking my problem lies in my routing, not the standard answers folks are using to correct their issues.

My issue:

I have an MVC4 app, runs fine from debug on localhost, but when publishing to the inetpub (on the same machine) I get 404 errors on pages that work normally from a start within VS2012.

I've tried some of the recommended remedies:

Make sure the Application pool targets correct version of .NET framework (i.e .NET Framework v4.0.30319 for .NET 4 and 4.5)

Make sure the Pipeline mode of IIS Application pool is "Integrated"

Check UrlRoutingModule-4.0 is added in the modules of that website.
(To do that, open list of added modules by clicking "Modules" against your website, and see if the module "UrlRoutingModule-4.0" is added or not). If not, then add a module by clicking "Add Managed Module" button, where select System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule as a Module type, and give "UrlRoutingModule-4.0" as its name)

Make sure you have following element added in system.webServer section of website's web.config

All of that is there. I just can't seem to figure out why the 404 errors persist.

Here's the setup: 
Windows 7 Enterprise, ver: 6.1 Build 7601 SP1
IIS version: 7.5

Also my routes listed in the RegisterRoutes() are:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "RPS",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

It's worth noting the "Default" routes for navigation: register, manage users, etc. seem to be working, but my "RPS" routes are not.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's the URL you got 404 on?

Comment: Vince, the URLS: "../Home/*" and "../Account/*" all seem to be fine. The unreachable URL is "../RPS/Index"

Comment: What's the intention for the "RPS" route. It's setup the same as the default route without specifying a default controller or default action. And do you have a RPS Controller with Index action method?

Comment: Yes. Forgive my naivete, as I'm new to MVC Routing, but I'm working with a different folder under the "Views" branch called "RPS" which has an associated controller. I'm trying to use this to force any urls with "../RPS/*" to use that routing. Is that correct?

Comment: You do not have to. The default view engine will look for views in the ~/Views/{controller} folder. For example, in a new ASP.NET MVC app with the default route, when you browse to /Home/Index, The Home controller Index action method will be executed, the ~/Views/Home/Index view will be rendered.

Comment: OK. Seems to be working now! Thanks! I think the error was actually a stupid one. I deployed the app as a branch inside the Default Web Site in IIS and the routes got tanked since it was adding another layer to the url... Just plain dumb on my part, but thanks for clearing up the extraneous route issue!